# How to fix sources list to get the MongoDB packages

Tags: apt, mongodb

I was reading a tutorial for mongoDB and it ended up to where I should have added a deb package in Ubuntu 11.10 sources list, I was able to find `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. I need to fetch the package from the following directory:

> http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/10gen/binary-amd64/

However I do not know actually what is the exact way of pointing to the package mongodb-10gen_2.2.0_amd64.deb in there.

I added the following but whenever I issue    sudo apt-get update    , it fails to fetch the package:

```
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/10gen binary-amd64 mongodb-10gen_2.2.0_amd64
```

Answer (score 2):

Going by [this tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list` file should look like this:

`deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen`

Make sure you add their repository signing key:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10`

Then:
`sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add the reposioty since you can just download the needed package from [here](http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/10gen/binary-amd64/mongodb-10gen_2.2.0_amd64.deb)

Then you can go to the downlaod directory and install it

```
cd /path-where-you-download-it

sudo dpkg -i mongodb-10gen_2.2.0_amd64.deb
```

**OR**

If you really want to add the repository

```
sudo echo "http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/10gen /binary-amd64/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can install **monogodb**

Comment: That's true, but without the repository you won't be made easily aware of security updates or bug fixes.

Comment: that sudo echo line won't work, because the redirect happens before the priv escalation.  You need to `echo $STUFF | sudo tee -a /path/to/file`.